# What is the difference between the default CV in Gridsearch and Kfold

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm wondering, what is the difference between the default cross validation that is implemented in GridSearchCV method in sklearn, and the Kfold method used with it, like in the following code:

without using Kfold:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameters, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')
clf = clf.fit(xOri, yOri)
```

with Kfold:

```
NUM_TRIALS = 5
    for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):
         cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
         clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=parameters, cv=cv, scoring='f1_macro')
         clf = clf.fit(xOri, yOri)
```

As I understood from the manual, is that both of them split the data into 10 parts, 9 for training and 1 for validation, but in the example that uses Kfold .. it does the sampling process 5 times (`NUM_TRIALS = 5`) and each time the data is shuffled before splitting into 10 parts. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks like you're right, ish.**

Either KFold or StratifiedKFold are used by GridSearchCV depending if your model is for regression (KFold) or classification (then StratifiedKFold is used).

Since I don't know what your data is like I can't be sure what is being used in this situation.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

But the code you have above will repeat the KFold validation 5 times with different random seeds.

**Whether that will produe meaningfully different splits of the data? Not sure.**